# Parse protobuf textformt to json without .proto (schema files)

Tags: python, json, protocol-buffers

Is it possible to parse protobuf text output (formatted text output, not the binary) into json.

Context: I have two protobuf text formats (similar,but not quite same), and I am trying to find differences (missing fields, different values for present fields), and doing it manually is time consuming and error prone.

Comment: It's "possible", but I'm not sure if there are any premade tools for this. Why do you need to convert to JSON in order to diff them? Maybe you could use textual diff tool that isn't format-dependent?